# How to evenly space links vertically within a div?

Tags: html, css

I am making a web app and I am needing the 4x links that are located in the middle column to be evenly spaced vertically and for the text inside the links to be horizontally and vertically centerd as-well.

The below picture is what I am after, please note that the website is going to be responsive. I want to avoid using flexbox at this stage as I have been running into some browser compatibility problems.

[CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByLQKr)

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


    <title>Runna - Track your run!</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/js.js"></script>
    <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <img src="imgs/logo-blue.png" />
  </header>
  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d11564.804405086046!2d172.59430635!3d-43.56069255!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sen!2snz!4v1418977732755" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
  <section class="control-container">
    <div class="column left">

    </div>
      <div class="column middle">
        <nav>
           <ul>
              <li>
                 <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
                 <a href="#">START</a>
                 <a href="#">STOP</a>
                 <a href="#">PAUSE</a>
              </li>
           </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    <div class="column right">

    </div>
  </section>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font: 100% arial;
  overflow: hidden;
}
@media all and (max-width: 150em) {

   header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5vh;
    background: black;
   }

   header img {

    height: 100%;

   }

   iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 65vh;
    display: block;
   }

   .control-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30vh;
    background: black;
    display: table;

   }
   .column {
    display: table-cell;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
   }

   .row {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;

   }

   .left {
    background: yellow;
    width: 33.3%;
    height: 100%;
   }

   .middle {
    background: black;
    width: 33.3%;
    height: 100%;
   }

   .right {
    background: red;
    width: 33.3%;
    height: 100%;

   }

   nav ul {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   }

   nav li {
   display: block;
   }

   nav a {
   color: white;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-align: center;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 30px;
   }

   nav a:hover {
      background: green;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `display: table` and `display: table-row`

```
.column.middle ul,.column.middle nav,.column.middle li {
    height: 100%;
}
.column.middle li {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.column.middle li a {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgp6w3od/4/)**

The above solution will work but as you can see the menu items are not vertically centered. To make them centered, I wrapped the menu items contents with a `div` element. and added the following css:

```
.column.middle li a div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgp6w3od/3/)**

Comment: Unless you need to support Internet Explorer 9, use Flexbox. [It is supported by every major browser](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox). You can use [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) for vendor prefixes.

Comment: @Mr_Green - it doesn't seem to work in Firefox which is interesting... I am using Firefox 34 on Windows. Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: @ifusion Strange, the problem seems to be because of `nav` element. I solved it using `position: absolute` to it. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgp6w3od/5/). btw, I didn't go deep on what could be the problem.. please check once.